# Path Specific Cookie in Django

Tags: django, cookies, cookie-path

i want to create cookie based authentication depends on path , 
so simply for testing i have create two views and set cookies respectively

**View 1** Cookie With globalLy available
[image]
**View 2** Cookie With Specific

[image]

But the problem in both view only global cookie is available

**View 1**
[image]

**View 2**
[image]

You can see both cookie have same name but different path, but when we get cookies only global cookie is available

if i display request.META.get('HTTP_COOKIE')) then all cookie are display but not in request.COOKIES.get('last_visit')

[image]

please help, i have tested in php , it works fine but not in python django

Comment: There is no solution in pythons community in world ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you face relates partly to Django, but firstly to the properties of HTTP cookies mechanism itself.

A cookie valid for a path is also valid for all its subpaths (a query string doesn't matter). So `last_visit` cookie intended for `/` is also valid for `/view2/`. For specifics of the matching mechanism, defining whether a cookie is suitable for a path, see [subsection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.4) "5.1.4. Paths and Path-Match" in RFC6265.

So both cookies are sent, and the order in which they are listed in `Cookie:` HTTP header is from more specific paths to less specifics ones. See [over here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#page-26) in RFC6265.

Now, Django processes cookies from the header one by one and populates a plain python dictionary `request.COOKIES`, rewriting values when keys are already present. That is how your value for `last_visit` is rewriten when both cookies for both paths are sent in http request.

While Django processes cookies like that, though it would be more reasonable to only keep the first (not the last) value for the key as it relates to more specific path, you can fix the issue by only using the same cookie names for paths of the same level -- for `/root/view1/` and `/root/view2/`, but not for `/root/`. Or You can divert cookie names with respect to http path like that:

```
import hashlib
cookie_name = 'last_visit%s' % hashlib.md5(request.path).hexdigest()
# ...
cookie = request.COOKIES.get(cookie_name)
# ...
response.set_cookie(cookie_name, cookie, path=request.path)
```